# How to install ubuntu in SSD after removing from HDD without loosing files? (My PC does not have separate partition)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, reinstall

I bought a DELL with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed on it. It becoming slow day by day. I am thinking of adding a SSD to my PC and installing the OS (Ubuntu 20.04) in there. Currently, the OS is installed on the HDD and I think there is no separate partition for my  files. Does removing the OS from HDD and installing it on SSD delete all my files? If so, then how to remove the os safely from the HDD and then install it to SSD with a separate partition ?

Please Help me Out!!
Thank You

[image: My Ubuntu Partition as shown in Disks]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following procedure:

1. Unplug the HDD
2. Plug in the SSD
3. Install Ubuntu 20.04 (or better 22.04) onto the SSD - nothing can go wrong there, because the HDD is unplugged
4. Once the PC is running with the new installation, additionally plug in the HDD. You might have to adjust the boot order in your BIOS so that it boots from SSD.
5. Then figure out which files you want to keep and delete the rest from the HDD.